# Java dividing incorrectly

Tags: java, int, double, divide

I am using Java 7

I am trying to get a double from dividing two integer:

```
double chance = 1/main.getConfig().getInt("dailygiftItems.items."+key+".chance");
double w = Math.random();
System.out.println("Pulled: "+main.getConfig().getInt("dailygiftItems.items."+key+".chance"));
System.out.println("itemChance: "+chance);
System.out.println("itemRand: "+w);
if(!(w < chance))continue;
```

However chance is returning 0. As you can see I have debugged all the values here is what they bring me:

Pulled: 5

itemChance: 0

itemRand: some random double (working correctly)

I was thinking if I did my math wrong and 5/1 is not 0.2 so I used a calculator. However the calculator returned to me 0.2.

I then tested on something simpler testing the same problem:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double chance = 1/5;
        double w = Math.random();
        System.out.println("Chance: "+chance);
        System.out.println("Random: "+w);
        if(!(w < chance))
        {
            System.out.println("no");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("yes");
    }

}
```

This produced the same result as:

Chance: 0

w: some random double (working)

My questions: Why is java not dividing this correctly, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you think you can get a double value if you divide two integers? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: If the values are 13/5 it will be a double

Comment: Result will be `2`, which is not correct.

Comment: I want the result to be a double so the result would not be 2. If the modifier was an int then yes.

Comment: If you divide two integer numbers, then the result will _always_ be an integer, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `double chance = 1./main.getConfig().getInt("dailygiftItems.items."+key+".chance");`

The `.` after `1` will force the compiler into considering this is a floating point (`double`) operation.

Comment: I would rather use `1d/` or `1.0/` or `(double) 1/`, although `1./` is valid it's very ugly to read

Comment: @BackSlash The only one that doesn't look ugly to me is `1.0`, but it's one more character to type :). Anyways, that's a matter of style and opinion.